# Access 2013 not prompting for password to push information to Sharepoint 2007, causing crashes

Tags: sharepoint-2007, ms-access-2013

We have a Sharepoint 2007 server with list that we enter information to through an Access Interface.

For awhile all of our users have been using Access 2010 with no problem.  However, a couple of our users have Access 2013 and are unable to use it to push information to Sharepoint.

I have narrowed it down to the password information not being passed to Sharepoint to let us send the data.

Our Access 2010 users have to enter their password each time they use it.

Our Access 2013 users are not prompted for a password and freeze up when they try to view a list connected to the Sharepoint server.

The only way Access 2013 does not freeze is if the user goes to External Data and use imports and links to the sharepoint site.  When they do this, they are asked for a username and password.

After they do this, they can click any of the list and use them as normal.  However, as soon as Access is closed the same issues occurs.

Is there a way to turn on password prompts for Access 2013?

I've looked at ways to retain that information, finding this useful site https://accessexperts.com/blog/2012/01/18/how-to-save-your-sharepoint-password-in-windows/.  However,none of our users have access to add a site to their trusted list and our IT department would sadly take weeks to do this.